# Getting django project to work with a different storage backend that serves gzip files

Tags: django, gzip

I am using uwsgi as the application server and nginx to serve static files. 
The setup fails when using a different `STATICFILE_STORAGE` that supports gzip/caching like `django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.ManifestStaticFilesStorage` or `'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'`

I end up getting the following errors when running DEBUG=False

```
Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/vagrant/envs/tuteria/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 137, in get_response
response = response.render()
File "/home/vagrant/envs/tuteria/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 103, in render
self.content = self.rendered_content
File "/home/vagrant/envs/tuteria/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/response.py", line 80, in rendered_content
content = template.render(context)
File "/home/vagrant/envs/tuteria/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 148, in render
return self._render(context)
File "/home/vagrant/envs/tuteria/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 142, in _render
return self.nodelist.render(context)
File "/home/vagrant/envs/tuteria/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 844, in render
bit = self.render_node(node, context)

File "/home/vagrant/envs/tuteria/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 858, in render_node
return node.render(context)

File "/home/vagrant/envs/tuteria/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 126, in render
return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "/home/vagrant/envs/tuteria/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 142, in _render
return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/home/vagrant/envs/tuteria/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 844, in render
bit = self.render_node(node, context)

File "/home/vagrant/envs/tuteria/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 858, in render_node
return node.render(context)

File "/home/vagrant/envs/tuteria/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 126, in render
return compiled_parent._render(context)

File "/home/vagrant/envs/tuteria/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 142, in _render
return self.nodelist.render(context)

File "/home/vagrant/envs/tuteria/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 844, in render
bit = self.render_node(node, context)

File "/home/vagrant/envs/tuteria/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 858, in render_node
return node.render(context)

File "/home/vagrant/envs/tuteria/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 65, in render
result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "/home/vagrant/envs/tuteria/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 844, in render
bit = self.render_node(node, context)

File "/home/vagrant/envs/tuteria/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 858, in render_node
return node.render(context)

File "/home/vagrant/envs/tuteria/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 898, in render
output = self.filter_expression.resolve(context)

File "/home/vagrant/envs/tuteria/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 596, in resolve
obj = self.var.resolve(context)

File "/home/vagrant/envs/tuteria/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 734, in resolve
value = self._resolve_lookup(context)

File "/home/vagrant/envs/tuteria/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 788, in _resolve_lookup
current = current()

File "/home/vagrant/envs/tuteria/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 74, in super
return mark_safe(self.render(self.context))

File "/home/vagrant/envs/tuteria/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/loader_tags.py", line 65, in render
result = block.nodelist.render(context)

File "/home/vagrant/envs/tuteria/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 844, in render
bit = self.render_node(node, context)

File "/home/vagrant/envs/tuteria/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/template/base.py", line 858, in render_node
return node.render(context)

File "/home/vagrant/envs/tuteria/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/templatetags/static.py", line 106, in render
url = self.url(context)

File "/home/vagrant/envs/tuteria/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/templatetags/staticfiles.py", line 16, in url
return static(path)

File "/home/vagrant/envs/tuteria/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/templatetags/staticfiles.py", line 9, in static
return staticfiles_storage.url(path)

File "/home/vagrant/envs/tuteria/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 128, in url
hashed_name = self.stored_name(clean_name)

File "/home/vagrant/envs/tuteria/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 277, in stored_name
cache_name = self.clean_name(self.hashed_name(name))

File "/home/vagrant/envs/tuteria/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/storage.py", line 91, in hashed_name
(clean_name, self))

ValueError: The file 'css/intlTelInput.css' could not be found with <django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.ManifestStaticFilesStorage object at 0xaae1f0c>.
```

I am able to run the `collectstatic` command without any issues. 
Below is my `uwsgi` configuration

```
[uwsgi]
socket = /tmp/tuteria.sock
master=True
pidfile = /tmp/tuteria-master.pid
enable-threads=True
processes = 1
chdir = /home/vagrant/workspace/
module = config.wsgi
virtualenv = /home/vagrant/envs/tuteria/
```

my settings file is as follows

```
STATIC_ROOT = join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'staticfiles')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
)
STATICFILES_STORAGE = DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.django.GzipManifestStaticFilesStorage'
# STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.staticfiles.storage.ManifestStaticFilesStorage'
# STATICFILES_STORAGE = DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'config.storages.GzipManifestPipelineStorage'
#
```

**NB**
I don't run into this issue when using the default STATICFILE_STORAGE

The error message shown here indicates that a particular static file could not be found. This error usually pop up when running `python manage.py collectstatic` but in this case, I only get this error when running the server with `uwsgi`. `collectstatic` fetches all the static files and gzips them without any issue.

Comment: This is not uwsgi related.

Comment: It might not be uwsgi related but I don't run into this issue when using gunicorn. The reason for this setup is I want to use `whitenoise` and a `cdn` to deploy my static files.

Comment: @gbozee Did you ever figure this out?  I'm in the same boat as you.

Comment: @gbozee Nevermind, I figured it out.  In my case, my "BASE_DIR" was different between gunicorn and wsgi.  I don't think it applies in your case...

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem in django 1.7 with ManifestStaticFilesStorage.

In the study of problems I found out if set DEBUG variable to True and run command collectstatic then static files will be collected. And in further command collectstatic will be working correctly with DEBUG=False

UPD: You can also deactivate your collectstatic backend, run collectstatic and again activate another collectstatic backend and run command